# Why isn't the base reformed in base-catalyzed hydrolysis of esters?

Tags: organic-chemistry, catalysis, hydrolysis

In acid-catalyzed hydrolysis, the hydronium ion is clearly reformed; however, in the base-catalyzed hydrolysis, an alcohol is formed as a by-product, but the strong base isn't reformed. Is it a misnomer to call it base "catalyzed"?

Comment: The initial products of saponification are a carboxylic acid and alkoxide. These two react to form a carboxylate and an alcohol, the leveling effect. The reaction is stoichiometric in base. In this sense you are correct, it is a misnomer.